# Change order of output from java List

Tags: java, list, sorting, output

I get a list with monthly data from the database. Currently I have sorted data from `January` to `December` as per database.

But I wanted output should be in order start from `June` and end month should be `May`.

Example output List:

```
    [
   {
    "accountlinevaluesId": 8,
    "accountlineId": 3,
    "month": "januar",
    "accountNumber": 177,
    "name": "Befestigungen",
    "amount": 0
},
{
    "accountlinevaluesId": 9,
    "accountlineId": 3,
    "month": "januar",
    "accountNumber": 179,
    "name": "Andere Bauten",
    "amount": -625
}, {
    "accountlinevaluesId": 165,
    "accountlineId": 4,
    "month": "februar",
    "accountNumber": 179,
    "name": "Andere Bauten",
    "amount": -625
},
{
    "accountlinevaluesId": 166,
    "accountlineId": 4,
    "month": "februar",
    "accountNumber": 210,
    "name": "Maschinen",
    "amount": -1962
}, {
    "accountlinevaluesId": 329,
    "accountlineId": 5,
    "month": "maerz",
    "accountNumber": 211,
    "name": "Testgestell",
    "amount": -897.75
},
{
    "accountlinevaluesId": 330,
    "accountlineId": 5,
    "month": "maerz",
    "accountNumber": 233,
    "name": "Motor f. Arbeitsplattfo",
    "amount": 0
}]
```

can someone tell me how I can best proceed and how I can solve this in Java?

current query looks like this:

```
public List<AccountlinevaluesEntity> findAllAccountLineValuesByMandantId(Long mandantId, String title, String context, String month) {
    List<AccountlinevaluesEntity> accountLineValues = new ArrayList();
    if (mandantId > 0 && title != null && context !=null) {
        try {
            List accountIds = new AccountManager().findAccountByMandantId(mandantId);
            startOperation(false);
            if (accountIds != null && accountIds.size() > 0) {
                List accountLineIds =
                        getSession()
                                .createQuery("SELECT ale.accountlineId FROM AccountlineEntity ale WHERE ale.accountId IN :accountIds AND ale.title = :title AND ale.context = :context")
                                .setParameter("accountIds", accountIds)
                                .setParameter("title", title)
                                .setParameter("context", context)
                                .list();
                if (accountLineIds != null && accountLineIds.size() > 0) {
                    if (month == null) {
                        return getSession()
                                .createQuery("SELECT alve FROM AccountlinevaluesEntity alve WHERE alve.accountlineId IN :accountlineIds")
                                .setParameter("accountlineIds", accountLineIds)
                                .list();
                    } else {
                        return getSession()
                                .createQuery("SELECT alve FROM AccountlinevaluesEntity alve WHERE alve.accountlineId IN :accountlineIds AND alve.month = :month")
                                .setParameter("accountlineIds", accountLineIds)
                                .setParameter("month", month)
                                .list();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            handleException(e);
        } finally {
            getSession().close();
        }
    }
    return accountLineValues;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to change the database query or is that not an option?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Read about comparators

Comment: Unfortunately not i need the list in frontend exactly the same but also as described above. would not like to use a second query

Comment: We dont even know how you get to that data, or how you print it. SO, please read [mcve] and show us your attempts to solve this problem, pointing out where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: If the logic says that the year begins, for example, in June, I would like to manipulate the list so that the output begins in June to may and not in January to december.
I would like to solve this in Java.

The data is sent to the frontend as Json. We use Angular for our frontend. But I only do the backend part

Answer (score 0):

If you can alter sql, it can be done using custom sorting logic.

```
SELECT name, *
FROM accounts

ORDER BY
    (
     CASE
       WHEN (month == 'June') THEN 1
       WHEN (month == 'July') THEN 2

       .......
        WHEN (month == 'May') THEN 12
     END
    ),
    name
```

Comment: The database is for **storing** your data. The **order** that you use to display it to the user is NOT something that the database should dictate. In other words: depending on user requirements, there might be 10 different ways to order the result of the query. So, when you need a custom order that goes beyond simple things, you should rather put the corresponding sorting into your business logic.

Comment: Perfectly said, it depends on situation. This is one of many possible approaches.

Comment: I was first about to say "what nonsense to that in SQL", but I think it really makes sense to know about all options. When you want to fetch 10 million entries from the DB, and you need one specific sorting, sure, let the DB do that for you. So, if you add something like "or do it in source code, depending your requirements", my upvote will be with you ;-)